# Reading files using fseek , fread and pointers

Tags: c, fread, fseek

I'm trying to manipulate images using c, and trying to fully understand `fseek()` and fread`()` mechanisms.

Why `fseek` did not change the address of point even it affected the `fread` function but did not change the point address or increase it?

Here is a simple example

```
int main()
{
    char *x[5]={"axxxx","aaaa","hxxx","rrrrr","xsdsdd"};
    char *point=x;
    char buffer[65]={0};

    fread(buffer,6,1,point);     //Here fread copy "axxx"
    fseek(point,5,SEEK_CUR);    //Here fseek increase point by five bytes
    fread(buffer,6,1,point);   // Here fread do nothing copy nothing
    printf("%s\n",buffer);    // buffer contain "axxx" first fread call
    printf("%x\n",point);    // point address did not changed because of fseek
    printf("%x",x);          //x still the same as point pointer

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fread` and `fseek` expect a file pointer (`FILE *`) as argument, not a character pointer `char *`. You should compile with warnings turned on.

Comment: `char *point=x;`  -> initializing `char` pointer with array of `char` pointers!!

Comment: `int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);`

Comment: @H.S. What's wrong with that? They're both char pointers aren't they?

Comment: @Zebrafish: `point` is of type `char *` and `x` is of type `char *[5]`.

Comment: @H.S. My mistake.

Comment: char *(*point)[5]=x; 
is that the right declaration @H.S. ?

Comment: Two votes to close because the question is "not about programming". What planet are the closers on?

Comment: @IDEN: correct declaration is - `char *(*point)[5]=&x;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread` should take a `FILE *` argument for the 4th parameter. You give a "char *".

What do you expect really here ?
`FILE` is an opact structure containing what we call a "position indicator". That's what allows to "move" in the file, `fseek` and `ftell`.

Your `char *` doesn't have that, your code is bugged.

Properly open a file with `fopen`.